# UnityPlayerActivity does not load cardboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

I am developing a project which includes Android app and Unity app. The main app is Android which at some point opens the Unity app. I exported the Unity app as Android plugin and integrated it in the Android studio as AAR module.
My Unity app uses Google VR SDK and it's implemented also for Cardboard. When I build Unity app normally (with .apk file) the Cardboard loads like it should (split screen). But when I export this app as a module in Android Studio, when I run UnityPlayerActivity the Cardboard view doesn't load, the scene is loaded like a normal Unity 3D scene.

Here are two screenshots of Android Studio Logcat:
[Logcat1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hufBX.png)
[Logcat2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etim4.png)

Here is also a screenshot of my Player Settings in Unity. Sometimes I want to load the Cardboard, sometimes not (depending on user's choice): [Unity Player Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX0q4.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding all gvr libraries to project manually: added lines to Project level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}
```

copied folder libs from project generated by Unity(which we use as library) to my project and added lines to app level build.gradle

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile(name: 'gvr-keyboard', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr-keyboardsupport-release', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr-permissionsupport-release', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'gvr', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'unitygvr', ext:'aar')
```

worked fine for me.